# Find $f,g$ s.t. $f\circ g=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\ 10 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, involutions

> Let $f$ and $g$ be permutations such that
>
> $$f \circ f = id,$$
>
> $$g \circ g = id,$$
>
> and
>
> $$f\circ g =\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
> 10 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> Find $f$ and $g$.

I can solve it by a lot of guess work, but I wonder if there is some general method.

Comment: When I tried doing a quick program to find solutions by brute force, it seems to have found 30 solutions total.

Comment: I suggest you accept answers to your previous questions also, especially one of the answers to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3015499/104041).

Comment: @DanielSchepler, your calculation agree with my solutions. As you can see from my answers the number of ways of choosing $f$ is $2\times 3\times 5=30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permutation $f$ is an *involution* if $f\circ f=id$.

As you know, any permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles; your permutation is $(1\ 10)(2\ 4\ 7)(3\ 5\ 8\ 6\ 9)$. In order to write an arbitrary permutation as a product of two involutions, it suffices (since disjoint permutations commute) to write a cycle of arbitrary length as a product of two involutions. A permutation is an involution if it's a product of disjoint cycles of length $2$. If you experiment a little with multiplying involutions, you might discover the following pattern:
$$(1\ 2)\circ(2\ 3)=(1\ 2\ 3)\tag3$$
$$(1\ 2)(3\ 4)\circ(2\ 3)=(1\ 2\ 4\ 3)\tag4$$
$$(1\ 2)(3\ 4)\circ(2\ 3)(4\ 5)=(1\ 2\ 4\ 5\ 3)\tag5$$
$$(1\ 2)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)\circ(2\ 3)(4\ 5)=(1\ 2\ 4\ 6\ 5\ 3)\tag6$$
etc. So a cycle of any length can be obtained by multiplying two involutions. In particular, replacing $1,2,3$ by $2,4,7$ in $(3)$ we get
$$(2\ 4\ 7)=(2\ 4)\circ(4\ 7);$$
replacing $1,2,4,5,3$ by $3,5,8,6,9$ in $(5)$ we get
$$(3\ 5\ 8\ 6\ 9)=(3\ 5)(9\ 8)\circ(5\ 9)(8\ 6)=(3\ 5)(8\ 9)\circ(5\ 9)(6\ 8);$$
and of course
$$(1\ 10)=(1\ 10)\circ id;$$
so
$$(1\ 10)(2\ 4\ 7)(3\ 5\ 8\ 6\ 9)=(1\ 10)(2\ 4)(3\ 5)(8\ 9)\circ(4\ 7)(5\ 9)(6\ 8).$$

I.e., you can take
$$f=(1\ 10)(2\ 4)(3\ 5)(8\ 9),\ g=(4\ 7)(5\ 9)(6\ 8).$$
Of course there are other solutions.

Comment: Your answer is essentially what I had in mind, @bof. [Do you agree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033171/find-f-g-s-t-f-circ-g-beginpmatrix1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10/3033500#comment6257730_3033500)

Comment: @Shaun I don't know what you had in mind, but I'll take your word for it. By the way, I thought an "idempotent" was an element $a$ satisfying $a^2=a$. So in a group the only idempotent is the identity element.

Comment: Thank you, @bof; and you're right: I meant *involution* of course. Here in England, it was late when I first wrote the answer and late when I came back to it. That's my excuse, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is a well-known algorithm for [decomposing any given permutation as a product of (not necessarily disjoint) $2$-cycles/transpositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702548/104041). Such a decomposition of a given $f\circ g$ would, in general, give strong hints about (if not completely determine) the nature of $f$ and $g$.

Why?

Because here $f,g$ are involutions: they square to the identity. Thus [they're each (either trivial or) determined by a product of disjoint $2$-cycles (a.k.a. transpositions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1618647/104041) (although they may share one or more of those cycles), which are themselves involutions.

---

See [@bof's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3034786/104041) for the same approach, fleshed out.

Comment: Well what you are saying is true. But here apart from $f$ and $g$ are idempotent we don't know yet what they are. So we can not apply the algorithm to decompose $f$ and $g$ into transpositions. So I don't see how the algorithm help you in this problem.

Comment: You're right, @user9077; thank you. The order of the paragraphs is backward (modulo some minor editing). Give me a minute . . .

Comment: Is it okay now, @user9077? (For reference: [Here's how it used to look.](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3033500/3))

Comment: I am not sure Shaun. Just give it a try if you can solve this particular problem using the idea that you have in your mind.

Comment: It's essentially [bof's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3034786/104041), @user9077.

Comment: Please would you confirm that, @bof?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it. First write $f\circ g$ as a product of disjoint cycles. So here $f\circ g=(1\, 10)(2\,4\,7)(3\,5\,8\,6\,9)$. Now

$$\begin{align}
g\circ f &=f\circ(f\circ g)\circ f \\
&=f\circ(f\circ g)\circ f^{-1} \\
&=(f(1)\,f(10))(f(2)\, f(4)\,f(7))(f(3)\,f(5),f(8)\,f(6)\,f(9)).
\end{align}$$

On the other hand $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}=g\circ f$. So from the provided $f\circ g$ we can invert it to get $g\circ f$ which is $$(1\,10)(2\,7\,4)(3\,9\,6\,8\,5)$$

Therefore $$(f(1)\,f(10))(f(2)\, f(4)\,f(7))(f(3)\,f(5),f(8)\,f(6)\,f(9))=(1\,10)(2\,7\,4)(3\,9\,6\,8\,5)$$ and we can define $f$ to satisfy this (notice $f$ is not unique). After this you can find your $g$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shaun. Do you happen to know my friend Hadi Susanto? :D

Comment: You're welcome, @user9077. I believe he and I had a brief conversation last year, yeah; I don't know if he remembers it though. He seems friendly. By the way, I nearly missed your comment as you didn't use the `@` thing (like I did in this comment with your username). Please be sure to use it in future :)